# How can I do a GROUP BY in Django without taking an aggregate function?

Tags: django, django-models

How can I do a GROUP BY in Django without invoking an aggregate function like Max, Sum, Avg, etc?

In my case, I have a table that has columns like `{ local_path, parent, grandparent }`, and I want to do `SELECT local_path FROM ... WHERE grandparent = "foo" GROUP BY parent`.  There will be multiple rows with a grandparent of "foo" and the same parent, but I just want one (any one) of their local_path's.

As you can see I don't want to take an aggregate value of anything.  And I couldn't get distinct() to work because I want to find non-distinct local_paths.

I've searched and read the documentation without any luck.  Thanks!

Comment: Interesting question as it's a rather odd non-deterministic SQL query. You can always use raw SQL though...

Comment: Yes, it looks like I'll have to go with raw SQL.  Thanks all!

Answer (score 7):

Here's a trick that works to get Django to execute a `GROUP BY` query without running an aggregate function. We make a custom `Func` subclass that is treated as an aggregate function by Django but actually just evaluates to `NULL` in a SQL query.

```
from django.db.models import Func, CharField


class NullAgg(Func):
    """Annotation that causes GROUP BY without aggregating.

    A fake aggregate Func class that can be used in an annotation to cause
    a query to perform a GROUP BY without also performing an aggregate
    operation that would require the server to enumerate all rows in every
    group.

    Takes no constructor arguments and produces a value of NULL.

    Example:
        ContentType.objects.values('app_label').annotate(na=NullAgg())
    """
    template = 'NULL'
    contains_aggregate = True
    window_compatible = False
    arity = 0
    output_field = CharField()
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use order_by('parent') then in the template use {% ifchanged %} to only show one of each.  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#ifchanged

Comment: In this case I'm not using a view.

Answer (score 0):

Does the SQL query work if you `GROUP BY parent` with a `WHERE grandparent =` and then you `SELECT local_path`? Shouldn't it complain that you are only allowed to `SELECT` aggregates of the "grouped-by" clause?

#### I want to find non-distinct local_paths

You don't say, so let me assume that `local_path` is a string, and that `parent` and `grandparent` are `ForeignKey`s in a `Model` called `Person`.

```
from collections import defaultdict
paths = defaultdict(list)  # parent_id -> list of paths to grandpa 'foo'

for parent_id in User.objects.filter(grandparent='foo').only('parent__id'):
    for path in User.objects.filter(grandparent='foo', parent__id=parent_id) \
        .only('local_path'):
        paths[parent__id] = path.local_path
```

`paths` will be a dict holding the values of `local_path` for different "parents" with `grandparent='foo'`

Comment: Yes the SQL query in the original post actually works.  I'm not a SQL expert but if you do a GROUP BY without an aggregate function, it just returns one matching row for each value in the GROUP BY clause.  Just by looking at your code I think it would work.  I was just hoping there'd be an easy way to do it with one DB query.  I suppose I'll just go with raw SQL.